# How to control AWK on which output field separators to change and which not

Tags: linux, awk

I have top 5 CPU utilizing processes with this command:

```
ps -eo pcpu,pmem,pid,ppid,cmd | sort -k 1,1nr | head -5
```

The Output:

```
 0.2  0.0  5037     1 /sbin/hpHelper -I0
 0.1  0.0  5567     1 cmahostd -p 15 -s OK -l /var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
 0.1  0.0  5839     1 cmanicd
 0.0  0.0    10     1 [watchdog/2]
 0.0  0.0 10689     1 cmasm2d -p 30 -l /var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
```

The fields are `CPU%,MEMORY%,PID,PPID,COMMAND`

I want the output to be comma separated with timestamp in the beginning of each line. However the last field which is `command` field should not be comma separated. I'm using the below:

```
ps -eo pcpu,pmem,pid,ppid,cmd | sort -k 1,1nr | head -5 | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1; print $0}'
```

which gives me an output:

```
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.2,0.0,5037,1,/sbin/hpHelper,-I0
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.1,0.0,5567,1,cmahostd,-p,15,-s,OK,-l,/var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.1,0.0,5839,1,cmanicd
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.0,0.0,10,1,[watchdog/2]
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.0,0.0,10689,1,cmasm2d,-p,30,-l,/var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
```

Whereas Output I'm expecting:

```
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.2,0.0,5037,1,/sbin/hpHelper -I0
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.1,0.0,5567,1,cmahostd -p 15 -s OK -l /var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.1,0.0,5839,1,cmanicd
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.0,0.0,10,1,[watchdog/2]
2016,05,22,00,26,19,0.0,0.0,10689,1,cmasm2d -p 30 -l /var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
```

How to modify the script to achieve this ?

Answer (score 2):

My idea to achieve this is that separate the output into two parts, the first part with `,` to be the separator, the last part with space for separation.

Here is the complete code,

```
ps -eo pcpu,pmem,pid,ppid,cmd | sort -k 1,1nr | head -5 | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1;  a="" ; b = ""; for (i =1; i<=4; ++i) a=a$i","; for (j = 5; j <= NF; j++) b = b " "$j; print a b; }'
```

The code for `awk` part only

```
awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, '{$1=dt OFS $1;  a="" ; b = ""; for (i =1; i<=4; ++i) a=a$i","; for (j = 5; j <= NF; j++) b = b " "$j; print a b; }'
```

Comment: That will replace all chains of contiguous white space in the commands with single blank chars so a command like `echo "foo<tab>bar"` would become `echo "foo<blank>bar"` and it will add a spurious blank char before the command.

Answer (score 2):

Give a try to this:

```
ps -eo pcpu,pmem,pid,ppid,cmd | sort -k 1,1nr | head -5 | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') '{printf("%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,",dt,$1,$2,$3,$4);$1=$2=$3=$4="";printf("%s\n",substr($0,5))}'
```

`OFS` is not used to handle any number of fields after the fifth one.

As noticed by @EdMorton, this will modify multiple blank chars in commands with single space char.

Another solution that would leave command unchanged and if the widths of the columns are fix:

```
ps -eo pcpu,pmem,pid,ppid,cmd | sort -k 1,1nr | head -5 | awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS="," '{print dt,$1,$2,$3,$4,substr($0,23)}'
```

Comment: I learn something again, thx @EdMorton. I am still reading the book from time to time.

The answer had been updated with an alternative solution, that is working if the widths are fix.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `cat file` with your `ps` command:

```
$ cat file | sort -k 1,1nr |
    awk -v dt=$(date +'%Y,%m,%d,%H,%M,%S') -v OFS=, 'NR<6{cmd=$0; sub(/^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){4}/,"",cmd); print dt,$1,$2,$3,$4,cmd}'
2016,05,21,18,37,49,0.2,0.0,5037,1,/sbin/hpHelper -I0
2016,05,21,18,37,49,0.1,0.0,5567,1,cmahostd -p 15 -s OK -l /var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
2016,05,21,18,37,49,0.1,0.0,5839,1,cmanicd
2016,05,21,18,37,49,0.0,0.0,10,1,[watchdog/2]
2016,05,21,18,37,49,0.0,0.0,10689,1,cmasm2d -p 30 -l /var/log/hp-snmp-agents/cma.log
```

Note you don't need to use `head`, awk can handle selecting the first 5 lines.

Comment: This gives me something like this: `2016,05,24,00,14,37,0.2,0.0,5037,1,0.2  0.0  5037     1 /sbin/hpHelper -I0`. Note `0.2,0.0,5037,1` have repeated themselves `0.2  0.0  5037     1` before the command

Comment: That's a shame. As you can see in my answer given input data that follows the format you posted and a POSIX awk the script I posted will produce the output shown so, assuming you've tried debugging it yourself, what do you think the problem is?